# Read CPU temperature from windows 10 running system using python

Tags: python, windows-10, wmi, cpu, openhardwaremonitor

I know that this question been asked many times, I even tried most of them, but I'm not satisfied on the results that I get.

First of all I'll explain my problem. I have tried the following code to get the cpu temperature (running it in admin mode):

```
import wmi
w = wmi.WMI(namespace="root\\wmi")
print ((w.MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature()[0].CurrentTemperature / 10) - 273.2)
```

Whenever I run the code, I get 25 as the result. I tried to increase the cpu temperature by opening lot of heavy applications. Even though the value didn't change.

I tried to check this value with another open source software named "Open Hardware Monitor" where the temperature changes every second and it was between 50 and 60.

I tried the following code also. The result is same as before (25):

```
from pyspectator.processor import Cpu
from time import sleep
cpu = Cpu(monitoring_latency=1)
while True:
    print (cpu.temperature)
    sleep(1)
```

I even tried the following code. It displays nothing.

```
import wmi
w = wmi.WMI(namespace="root\OpenHardwareMonitor")
temperature_infos = w.Sensor()
for sensor in temperature_infos:
    if sensor.SensorType==u'Temperature':
        print(sensor.Name)
        print(sensor.Value)
```

Now coming to my question.

- Is 25 the right value? If so, How to increase / decrease the cpu temperature? (to test the result)
- What will be the normal and maximum cpu temperature?
- Why "Open Hardware Monitor" software showing different value?

Extra note: I'm using python 3.6, windows 10, processor - Intel core i7

Comment: What's the output of `print(w.MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature))`?

Comment: [<_wmi_object: b'\\\\root\\wmi:MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature.InstanceName="ACPI\\\\ThermalZone\\\\THM__0"'>]

Comment: Result of print(w.MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature()[0]) is here:  instance of MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature
{
        Active = TRUE;
        ActiveTripPoint = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        ActiveTripPointCount = 0;
        CriticalTripPoint = 3802;
        CurrentTemperature = 2982;
        InstanceName = "ACPI\\ThermalZone\\THM__0";
        PassiveTripPoint = 0;
        Reserved = 0;
        SamplingPeriod = 0;
        ThermalConstant1 = 0;
        ThermalConstant2 = 0;
        ThermalStamp = 36;
};

Comment: Can you access items with other indices like `[1]`?

Comment: Nope. When I try to execute print(w.MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature()[1]), I'm getting "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: Waiting to get help regarding this issue...

Comment: Did you try executing this code on other machines?

Comment: yes I tried the first code (ie) import wmi
w = wmi.WMI(namespace="root\\wmi")
print ((w.MSAcpi_ThermalZoneTemperature()[0].CurrentTemperature / 10) - 273.2) ... It prints 26 in that machine